# Symfony2, Service with variable as argument

Tags: symfony, variables, service

Is it possible to pass a variable as an argument to a service?

I have a service that does some stuff with the entity-manager.
Something like:

```
$this -> container -> get('getuser')->setArgument2($someVariable);
```

Is that SOMEHOW possible?

config.yml

```
services:
getuser:
    class: fancypathtoservice
    arguments: [@doctrine.orm.entity_manager]
```

My service:

```
class GetUser
{
public function getuserAction($userid)
{

    $em = $this->em;

    $query = $em->createQuery(
        'SELECT p
FROM SomeBundle:User p
WHERE p.userid = :id'
    )->setParameters(array(
            'id' => $userid,
        ));

    $user = $query->getResult();
    $user = $user[0];

    return $user;
}

protected $em;

public function __construct(EntityManager $entityManager)
{
    $this->em = $entityManager;
}
}
```

And in the controller i call

```
$player = $this -> container -> get('getuser');
```

Now i need the controller to pass the $userid to the service. Is that possible somehow?

Regards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you can! (But I never needed to)

However you have to be aware that the default scope of a service is `container` (which means it will be the same instance for the full request).

Example:

```
<?php
namespace Bundle\Service;

class GetUserService
{
    protected $argument2;

    public function setArgument2($argument2)
    {
        $this->argument2 = $argument2;
    }
}
```

-

```
#services.yml
services:
    getuser:
        class: Bundle\Service\GetUserService
```

You can now set the variable **$argument2**.

However as already mentioned I never do it this way.

## Inject Services into services

I usually inject other services as arguments in the constructor for example:

```
<?php
namespace Bundle\Service;

class GetUserService
{
    protected $em;

    public function __construct($em)
    {
        $this->em = $em;
    }
}
```

-

```
#services.yml
services:
    getuser:
        class: Bundle\Service\GetUserService
        arguments: [@doctrine.orm.entity_manager]
```

## Submit arguments to the service call

And if I have an argument that differs on each service call I simply submit it on the method as an argument:

```
<?php
namespace Bundle\Service;

class GetUserService
{
    public function add($a, $b)
    {
        return $a+$b;
    }
}
```

Comment: ```$this->container->get('getuser')->getuserAction($userid);```

Comment: thank you so much. can't believe i didn't figure that out myself. well..guess you never stop learning.

Comment: You could accept my answer. ;) Btw you could just do ```$em->getRepository('SomeBundle:User')->find($userid);``` and ```$user= $query->getSingleResult(); ```
You could post your code to: http://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: i know, there service is doing more, i just cut it out because it wasn't relevant in here.